# How to find the variance of a discontinuous function?

Tags: normal-distribution, variance, random-variable

Let's say I have a standard normally distributed random variable X.

Let's say I have a function f(X) such as the following:

```
f(X) = -.5 + .5(X + .5) for X < -.5
f(X) = X for -.5 <= X < .5
f(X) = .5 + 1.5(X - .5) for X >= .5
```

Is it possible to get a theoretical variance for f(X)?

Comment: I am not aware of any restriction, in any common definition of variance, to continuous functions.  What definition of variance are you thinking of?

Comment: I'm thinking of Var(f(x)) = E[f^2(x)] - (E[f(x)])^2.  The function I specified is discontinuous at -.5 and .5.

Comment: Does your definition of expectation exclude discontinuous functions?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your question.  I can simulate and see that my function has an E[f(x)] of around .2.  I'm not sure how to even get to that point when it is discontinuous.  Using the normal distribution, I know that I get f(x)=x around 38% of the time, and the other two versions around 31% of the time each.  I was going to try to weighted average the moments of the individual functions to those probabilities, but I'm just going by feel.

Comment: What is your definition of expectation?  I'm sure that it doesn't refer to simulation... .  BTW, the function in your question does not appear to be discontinuous anywhere.

Comment: Your function is continuous but not everywhere-differentiable. You don't need continuity to get a variance though. Have you seen the [law of the unconscious statistician](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician)?

Comment: Thanks, Glen_b and whuber.  I have seen that law before.  But I'm not sure what I should do in this particular case?  Do I need to use Ito-calculus, or can I get away with easier tools?  My definition of expectation is the average/expected value when using the function via the random variable.  I don't really see what you are getting at...  expected value seems straightforward to me, but I may be missing something there.